# Oracle Apex 5 - is it mis-behave ( default Form not showing data )

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Trying to create a Form on Table/View in Oracle Apex 5, when running it not fetching / showing any data... It has created a process under After Header to fetch rows from table? I generate using its wizard to check the functionality.
Please help, is it normal ? If it is normal that whey it created a Process to fetch data automatically from Table?

regards.

Comment: Do you have any issue with form?

Comment: it seems like an issue... as mentioned, i generated a Form on Table/View with its wizard, this form contains only 1 table, when checked it has created a Process under Pre-rendering -> After Header -> Processes to fetch data automatically but when running this form it is not showing any data.

Comment: It is normal for a process to be generated by the wizard to handle the fetching of your data from the database. As for not showing any data, you will need to provide more information in order for someone to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Drumbeg   please, i can't understand to provide more information. what is else to mention as i didn't do anything just generate a form with its own wizard and run to check it...

Answer (score 0):

This type of forms is designed for editing a row in a table. If you look at the content of your page, you can see a hidden item with name like `P123_ID` or `P456_ROWID` - it is an ID of a row which will be shown on a page load. Default value of this item is `NULL`, so when you just start freshly created page, you will see the page in "create new row" mode. You can fill fields and click "Save", and new row will be added to the table. If you want to see some data in fields, you have to put an ID of desired row in ID item. There is a number of ways how to do that: set default value for the item, pass value in a link, etc.

**UPD**
You can't change the "mode of page" directly (there is no such thing in APEX), APEX decide what to show depending on value of ID item. If it is `NULL`, APEX shows page for adding new row, if it is not `NULL` - editing existing row. Simplest way to edit existing rows: you need also a page with report (page type `Classic report` or `Interactive report`), in report you need to create column link with properties: `target page` - number of page with "form on table or view", `item 1` - name of item with ID, `value 1` - name of a column with ID in report.
If you are new to APEX, it is quite hard to make all of that. You need to learn following:

- how to create report with links in column
- how to set value of page item using URL
- optionally - structure of APEX URL

Each of this topics is quite simple, but too big to describe here.

Comment: thank you for the hints to make it workable. i am modifying my page now and will add some functionality to Search on the page to retrieve the database records. then i will try to add another region for a Tabular form and make a Master-Detail relationship manually. hope i can do it, when finish i will return here to mention what i did to achieve it.

Comment: can you please guide from where i can change " mode of page "  any link or help will be highly appreciated.  thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, i am new to Apex, actually i am a PLSQL developer and here at work they need me to explore Apex to switch Oracle Developer Forms & Reports to. i will responsible to teach other developers and we will develop all application modules in Apex.if you interested, i can give you my workspace details at apex.oracle.com to review what i done yet. if i will be guided by you people, as above, this can save my job.